# Is CORS issue unique to AngularJS applications?

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api, cors

I'm building a client side application with AngularJS that makes requests to a RESTful Web API built with ASP.NET. I have had the "No Access-Control-Allow-Origin Header is Present" error and I understandt that in order to fix it you need to allow CORS in your web API which I have done.

What I do not understand, however, is why I have this issue only with AngularJS applications. I have built many client side applications in ASP.NET MVC that consume services from an ASP.NET web API and I have never ran into this issue. Can someone shed some lights on why this happens?

Comment: CORS issue is no way related to Angular. Try making an ajax call using plain jQuery to a CORS disabled API, you will get that error.

Comment: It's not unique. When you get data from a different domain this security will kick in and block the request. Do you run your angularjs app on the same domain as the web api?

Comment: They're both running on different local host addresses.

Comment: is the problem that its not working? or did you get  it to work?

Comment: I did get it to work but not in the manner that I wanted. I had to add [EnableCors(" * ", " * "," * ")] which allows requests from all origins to my controller class instead of [EnableCors("http://localhost:48340/", " * "," * ")] because it didn't work.

Comment: try this [EnableCors(" * ", " * "," * ")] . Notice the *'s. (NB: Had to insert spaces before and after * because of some formatting ;S)

Comment: Yes, that's what I did. But that approach allows any origin to call my API, and I only want my angular application. The supposed solution was to set the origin address in the contructor like this [EnableCors("localhost:48340/", " * "," * ")] but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not unique for AngularJS. It's like this for all javascript calls going to a different domain than the one it's in.

The difference might be that you called the web service from the server of the MVC project.

Whilst, calling an API from the front end (Browser), the browser has built in security that doesn't allow you to do calls to a different domain. The server does not have the same built-in security as the browsers.

Comment: It is true, yet angular added some limit ot this : you can't use json on other methods than GET in angularJS. I don't clearly remember the limitation of those, and i can't find a well documented link. I saw soe question on SO showing that some had to change the header to the FROM one instead of json to have the request allowed by angularJS. ANd there is something about json/jsonp too but still i didn't find a really suitable link.

Comment: i have never really had this problem. Must have been an edge case of some sort.

Comment: But I have both applications on the same visual studio solution. Shouldn't it be using the same server when running the apps?

Comment: What do you mean? The angular code and the web api you are trying to call is in the same web project?

Comment: Not quite. They're in the same solution. I have a solution which has two different projects. An ASP.NET Web API and a Website, the latter being the AngularJS app. I'm guessing this has nothing to do with problem, right?

Comment: alright. Therefore, they are in different domains. Which will cause the built-in security in the browser to kick in. How did you call the web-api from the MVC project, was it from the actions in the controllers or from javascript?

Comment: I created an HttpClient helper class that had the address of the API, and then in the controllers I specified the path (ex: api/Products) and made the call.

Comment: Right. When you do it from the controllers it is done server-side. Therefore, the browsers built-in security will not kick in. Server-side calls does not have these security limitations. You can of course implement them if you want.

Comment: Okay, understood!!! Thank you so much! *edit* Thanks to everyone in the post, all of your insights on this matter helped me a lot. For logistic reasons I have chosen this answer as the correct but the other answers and responses were extremely helpful as well.

Comment: Great! Remember, Javascript in the browser (Chrome, IE, etc) is client-side. Actions and controllers are server-side.

Comment: Thanks, I won't be forgetting about that from now on!

Answer (score 1):

CORS is a browser based technology, and is not limited to Angular. Angular leverages XMLHttpRequest to make it's requests, which is using the Same-origin policy. The reason that your other client-side applications are working is because they are not browser based.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

Answer (score 1):

No. It is not unique to Angular.

You will run into CORS issues when your backend API and frontend SPA have a different one of the following:

- Host Name: `api.example.com` and `www.example.com`
- Port: `example.com` and `example.com:8080`
- Protocol: `https://example.com` and `http://example.com`

Comment: So, basically, because ASP.NET MVC isn't SPA and is running on the server is the reason why I don't have the CORS issue with ASP.NET MVC applications calling a Web API?

Comment: Yes, you can get around the CORS issue by either hosting your SPA from your ASP.NET application or hosting the API at a subdomain, or reverse proxying one into the the others path -- or just setting up the CORS headers in your WebAPI.